# Installing Android SDKr18, SDK will not detect the JDK

Tags: android, sdk, java

![enter image description here][1]Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

This is not another back, then next problem.

I have installed eclipse classic and jdk-7u3-windows-x64, the problem is when I go to install the android SDK, I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9VIY.jpg

I have been searching the net all night, one solution seems to be for an earlier version of the Android SDK is to click back then next, I have tried this to no avail. 
I have also set up a environment variable, this didn't work either. 
I have checked that java has definitely been installed, I have run and installed all software as admin. Still I get the same message.

So can anyone out there help me with this issue?

Big thanks in advance for any help!

Nick.

Comment: try some [jdk-6 32 bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html) - you can't use the features of 7 and 64bit makes only problems (Android apps have to be compiled 32 bit)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, I have now tried this and the sdk installer now crashes, http://i.stack.imgur.com/fc4hh.jpg . Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with Windows 7 - 64 bit machine. The installation of the Andriod SDk wil l hang on the screen where it is trying to locate JDK. I had both 64 and 32 bit JDK installed. JAVA_HOME was set to correct JDK (32) bit to C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_13 but the installer will get stuck in a loop and will never recover from the screen.

It is silly really but what I had to do was, to reinstall jdk-6 32 bit in a different directory this time (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31) , change the JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31 and reinstall  SDK.
Very strangely it didn't pick up new installation of JDK at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31 as set in the JAVA_HOME, instead it picked up my old installation from C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\

Someone really need to check their codes at Google!!

But sorted , I am happy

Answer (score 1):

I think all the installed and uninstalling of java caused the above error. Anyway restored my computer back to a certain point and installed the jdk 6 32 instead to start with. The sdk found it straight away.